# How to optimize this inner join query to decrease query time

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table that now has about 1m rows. The following query need about 5 seconds to complete. What you suggest optimizing query speed?

```
# Thread_id: 14  Schema: defrop_defrop  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 5.573048  Lock_time: 0.591625  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1006391
# Rows_affected: 1
UPDATE `backlinks` as a
INNER JOIN(SELECT b.`id` as bid
           FROM `backlinks` b
           WHERE b.`googlebot_id` IS NULL AND b.`used_time` IS NULL AND 
b.`campaign_id` IN  (SELECT `id` FROM `campaigns` WHERE `status`=true) GROUP BY b.`campaign_id` ORDER BY RAND() limit 1
           ) as c
 ON (a.id = c.bid)
SET a.`crawler_id` = '10.0.0.13', a.`used_time`=NOW();
```

campaign_id, googlebot_id are foreing keys, indexers.
used_time and crawler_id are indexers
Screenshot from the table phpmyadmin
[image: Phpmyadmin table backlinks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the query formatted so I can read it better:

```
UPDATE backlinks bl JOIN
       (SELECT bl2.id as bid
        FROM backlinks bl2
        WHERE bl2.googlebot_id IS NULL AND
              bl2.used_time IS NULL AND 
              bl2.campaign_id IN (SELECT c.id FROM campaigns c WHERE status = true)
       GROUP BY b.campaign_id
       ORDER BY RAND() 
       LIMIT 1
     ) bl2
     ON bl.id = bl2.bid
    SET bl.crawler_id = '10.0.0.13',
        bl.used_time = NOW();
```

First, the `GROUP BY` in the subquery is not needed.  And I would replace the `IN` with `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE backlinks bl JOIN
       (SELECT bl2.id as bid
        FROM backlinks bl2
        WHERE bl2.googlebot_id IS NULL AND
              bl2.used_time IS NULL AND 
              EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM campaigns c WHERE bl2.campaign_id = c.id AND c.status = true)
        ORDER BY RAND() 
        LIMIT 1
      ) bl2
      ON bl.id = bl2.bid
    SET bl.crawler_id = '10.0.0.13',
        bl.used_time = NOW();
```

That will help a little, but probably not much.  My guess is that the performance issue is the size of the outer sort (or equivalently, the size of the data needed for the `GROUP BY` in your query).

You can also get rid of the subquery entirely:

```
UPDATE backlinks bl
    SET bl.crawler_id = '10.0.0.13',
        bl.used_time = NOW()
WHERE bl.googlebot_id IS NULL AND
      bl.used_time IS NULL AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM campaigns c WHERE bl.campaign_id = c.id AND c.status = true)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

This has minimal impact, but it cleans up the logic a bit.

My guess is that the `WHERE` conditions are not very selective, so optimizing them won't help much.

At this point, the issue is the `ORDER BY RAND()`.  If you have any idea how many rows are being returned by the subquery, then you can pre-filter using `RAND()`.  For instance, let me assume that there are at least 1,000 rows being returned.  Then:

```
UPDATE backlinks bl
    SET bl.crawler_id = '10.0.0.13',
        bl.used_time = NOW()
WHERE bl.googlebot_id IS NULL AND
      bl.used_time IS NULL AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM campaigns c WHERE bl.campaign_id = c.id AND c.status = true) AND
      RAND() < 0.01  -- keep about 1/100
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

This significantly speeds the sort, because it is on 100th the data.  However, it could filter out all rows -- if not enough rows match the conditions.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for the quick response. I am using GROUP BY because i want to get only backlinks.id per campaign_id, this way all campaigns have exactly the same chance to provide 1 backlinks.id.

Comment: @Heopas . . . You are returning only one row, so that doesn't matter.  If you want one per campaign, then ask a *new* question, explain the logic you want to implement, and provide sample data and desired results.   Your query is only updating one row.  If you change this question, you will invalidate this answer, which can draw downvotes -- and that is rather rude.